# Does the use of salbutamol by a asthma sufferer significantly improve his sport performances?

Tags: sports, asthma

I was born a asthma sufferer. My asthma can be triggered by both sport and allergenes. I use a Ventolin inhaler (thus containing the active substance called "[salbutamol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salbutamol)") when the asthma becomes really uncomfortable.

I have seen significant improvement in my comfort during endurance sport (such as running or cycling) when I use Ventolin before doing it (no matter if I feel ok or not regarding my asthma). It is a well-known doping product used by endurance athletes (including those who do actually not suffer from asthma), so that it made me wonder if the comfort improvement was due to the fact it not only "diminish my asthma" but also improve my performance as it would for someone healthy (not suffering from asthma).

Suppose there exists someone who has the exact same body as I have, but without the asthma problem. Is it possible that this drug improve my performance in such a way it makes me significantly* better than such a person (who does not take the drug)?

EDIT: even if the Wikipedia page says that there is "no compelling evidence that salbutamol [...] can increase performance in healthy athletes" (citing [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2439523/)), I have often heard (but don't know if it is true) that many endurance athletes use salbutamol, so I really doubt it does not improve performance if they take it. Moreover, only one study does not seem enough to confirm a fact as most likely true (in a scientific perspective). So I am asking here for facts backed by different scientific sources.

*significantly is vague and subjective, but can be understood as follows: a "significantly better performance of an athlete over another" consists in "this athlete completely outclassing the other one".

Comment: If placebo controlled trials point out that they it doesn't work, and theoretical arguments point out that it may have negative effects,but athletes keep on using it because they say it does wonders for them, then I suspect that [it does work but not because of the active ingredient](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x1z4iyq_e07-the-power-of-the-placebo_tv).

Comment: @CountIblis Thank you. This is an interesting point but I am far from believing the result of only one study just because it respects the scientific methodology (but I suppose there are many studies on this). Of course, if done by respected people in the field, we may believe the result is right, but I think it is preferable to have different studies made by different people on the same subject before considering the results as "definitive".